# How to convert the JSON date with to_date function

Tags: oracle11g, to-date

**How to convert the specific string `Aug 6, 2018 3:17:11 PM` with the function `to_date`?**

That string is a result of a Java parsing mechanism for JSON. I would like to be able to recover it directly from oracle.

> My real problem is much more comprehensive that looks to be. It evolves the APEX_JSON usage, but it is not the question. [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1711e4/6) something near of real scenario.

Comment: Has Java parsed it into a string, or into a date/timestamp and it's just being displayed like that e.g. via `toString()`? What do mean by 'directly from Oracle' - do have a JSON object you want to get the value from directly.? If so please include the JSON in your question.

Comment: @AlexPoole I created a sqlfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Mon DD, YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM` format model:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/512)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
         'Aug 6, 2018 3:17:11 PM',
         'Mon DD, YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'
       ) As dt
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/512/0)**:

```
|                   DT |
|----------------------|
| 2018-08-06T15:17:11Z |
```

Comment: MT0, are there no differences between `PM` and `AM` in the oracle format model?

Comment: @GeisonSantos [Oracle Format Model documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) - [TL;DR] no differences.